# ffmpeg, msys, make: команда не найдена

Tags: ffmpeg, mingw, makefile

пытаюсь настроить ffmpeg, следуя этой инструкции https://pracucci.com/compile-ffmpeg-on-windows-with-visual-studio-compiler.html
Когда дохожу до команды make, пишет, что она не найдена.
configer заканчивается с предупреждением  pkg-config not found, library detection may fail.
Кроме этого yasm "не была найдена либо устарела"поэтому пришлось написать --disable-yasm.

Comment: А что говорит `echo %PATH%`? Добавился ли путь?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду путь к yasm? да, добавился

Comment: А из-под msys_shell что говорит `which make`?

Comment: which: no make in (/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/Common...)

Comment: Ага, ну тогда никакой мистики. Поищите, где реально находится ваш `make` (где-то в msys2), и добавьте его в PATH.

Comment: к make или Makefile ? не помогло

Comment: А что вы конкретно сделали? Должно было помочь, по идее.

Comment: добавила в PATH путь к файлу make

Comment: Окей, и теперь `which make` всё равно его не находит? (Может быть, надо перегрузиться.)

Comment: сделала, не помогло

Comment: Окей, а в списке каталогогов, которые выдаёт `which`, есть каталог с `make`? (То есть, добавился он реально или нет?) И что говорит `echo %PATH%` (или `echo $PATH`), есть там нужный каталог, или нет?

Comment: make в MSYS2 надо установить через команду: pacman -Su make. Программы "make" по умолчанию в MSYS2 нет почему-то.